# Change menubar in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, menubar

Hy,

I have managed to make a top menu bar in Zend Framework and the code is placed in `layouts/scripts/layout.phtml`, and i have the followind items: `Item1`, `Item2`, `Item3`, `Login`, `Register`. What i want is that when somebody logs in, to change the last 2 elements, replace `Login` and `Register` with `Logout`. Can someone help me with something please? I readed something about placeholders, but i don`t understand them clearly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it sounds like you are using a view-script (rather `Zend_Navigation`) for your menu, it should relatively straightforward to include a check as follows right in `layouts/scripts/layout.phtml`:

```
// Render your static menu elements
// render, render

// Now handle the dynamic part
if (!Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()){
    // Render the `Register` and `Login` links.
} else {
    // Render your `Logout` link.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a very simple answer but yet, very efficient. But it is more convinient and correct to make with `Zend_Navigation` ?

Comment: It's more "Zend-ish" to do it via `Zend_Navigation`. And it offers lots of cool stuff like marking (via CSS class) which link is active on the current page, for selecting a sub-set of those links in the nav container (perhaps for use in a sidebar menu), and for creating breadcrumbs. While I sometimes (often!) find it a pain to get things to render the way I want, I find it conceptually satisfying to separate the "nav data" from its various uses (like menu, sub-menu, breadcrumbs, etc).

Comment: Thanks David, i will try the Zend_Navigation too, hope i will get it how it works.